# PyQGIS 3.16 Print Layout Map Item does not render

Tags: print-composer, pyqgis-3

I am trying to create a print layout with a map item representing certain layers of my project. For some reason, the map item is created and the code runs correctly, creating de layout and adding the map with the specified size, but doesn't finish rendering.

Here are the lines of code I am working with:

```
        layer1 = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Almacen Tracks')
        layer2 = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Almacen Avifauna_planeadoras')
        if len(QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Almacen Colisions')) != 0:
                layer3 = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Almacen Colisions')
                col= layer3[0]
        layer4 = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Fondo/Mosaico/Ortoimagen')

        tracks= layer1[0]
        plan= layer2[0]
        pnoa=layer4[0]
        project = QgsProject.instance()
        manager = project.layoutManager()
        layoutName = 'Layout1'
        layouts_list = manager.printLayouts()
        for layout in layouts_list:
            if layout.name() == layoutName:
                manager.removeLayout(layout)
        layout=QgsPrintLayout(project)  
        layout.initializeDefaults()
        layout.setName(layoutName)
        manager.addLayout(layout)

        map = QgsLayoutItemMap.create(layout)
        map.setRect(QRectF(10, 10, 210, 90))
        map.setFrameEnabled(True)
        canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
        canvas.setExtent(col.extent())
        map.setExtent(canvas.extent())

        layout.addLayoutItem(map)
        map.attemptMove(QgsLayoutPoint(10,10))
        map.attemptResize(QgsLayoutSize(210,100))
        map.setScale(1000,True)
```

[image: Resulting print layout]

Does anyone know what am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I have tried this code on the python console and it works, the problem appears when I run it trough a script.

Comment: What do you meany "through a script" ? A standalone script ? A script inside QGIS Desktop ?

Comment: A script inside QGIS Desktop